# How to get auto-increment values after inserting records using SqlBulkCopy via c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sqlbulkcopy

I am using **SqlBulkCopy** class to insert bulk records but i want that newly generated `auto-increment` values(primary key plays Foreign key in child table) because with the help of that values i am going to play with child tables(Foreign key) making insert.

Please follow the below example to get the clear picture,

Source table: Create table StagingTable (personName varchar(50))
insert into StaginTable values('Test1')
..
..
..
insert into StaginTable values('Test10,000')

**Target table:** Create table TargetTable (personId int identity(1,1), personName varchar(50))
insert into TargetTable values('Already1')
..
..
insert into TargetTable values('Already10')

Now I am having 10 records in TargetTable with 10 records with personId (1 to 10), so my question is to insert 10,000 records from StagingTable to TargetTable & make it as 10,010 records  meantime I need only 10,000 unique identity values by excluding 10 identity values with the help of merge concept in sql server 2012.

Create procedure Merge_GetNewIdentityValues
As
MERGE TargetTable AS T
USING StagingTable AS S
ON 1 != 1
when not matched then
insert(personName) values(S.StagingTable)
output inserted.personId; -- Get the identity field values [newly inserted one]

How can this be handled in concurrency? Whether "inserted" keyword plays in separate context or single context used for different users to call the same stored procedure

Thanks,
S.Venkatesh

Comment: Please post your code of insert

Comment: What's the problem? You want to preserve identity for bulk insert or you don't want it? Does your table has identity primary key?

Comment: Possibly useful: [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) (I use bulk-copy + MERGE here.)

Comment: Yes my parent table has identity primary key. The problem is parent/child tables bulk insert using sqlbulkcopy (Once i know the parent tables identity values then only i can play with child table)